# in Flutter how to call the validate in the DefaultTabController before the swiper, preventing it from sliding if there was validation

Tags: flutter, validation, tabs

```
    class CadastrarCliente extends StatefulWidget {
      Cliente cliente;
      Veiculo veiculo;
      CadastrarCliente({this.cliente, this.veiculo});
      @override
      _CadastrarClienteState createState() => _CadastrarClienteState();
    }
    
    User u = User();
    UserHelper h = UserHelper();
    Future<User> getAssociacao() async {
      u = await h.getUser();
      return u;
    }
    
    class _CadastrarClienteState extends State<CadastrarCliente>
        with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
      Cliente _editedCliente;
      Veiculo _editedVeiculo;
      Future<User> usuario;
      var idAssociacao;
      String valorFipe;
      int _currentStep = 0;
      var value, label;
      Financeiro financeiro = Financeiro();
      // final _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    
      List<GlobalKey<FormState>> _formkeys = [
        GlobalKey<FormState>(),
        GlobalKey<FormState>(),
        GlobalKey<FormState>(),
        GlobalKey<FormState>(),
        GlobalKey<FormState>()
      ];
      final scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
      TabController _tabController;
      int _selectedIndex = 0;
      List<Widget> listTab = [
        Tab(text: 'Cliente'),
        Tab(text: 'Veículo'),
        Tab(text: 'Contrato'),
        Tab(text: 'Financeiro'),
      ];
      var _checkboxZeroKm = false;
    
      DateTime _dataNota;
      var _ctrlIdAssociacao = TextEditingController();
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _tabController = TabController(length: listTab.length, vsync: this);
```

veryfi swiper:

```
        _tabController.addListener(() {
          setState(() {
            print(
                'Testando ${_formkeys[_tabController.index - 1].currentState} e Index ${(_tabController.index - 1).toString()}');
            if (_formkeys[_tabController.index - 1].currentState.validate()) {
              print("Selected Index: " + (_tabController.index).toString());
            }
          });
        });
        if (widget.cliente == null) {
          _editedCliente = Cliente();
        } else {
          _editedCliente = widget.cliente;
          _editedVeiculo = widget.veiculo;
        }
      }
    
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return DefaultTabController(
          length: 4,
          child: Scaffold(
            key: scaffoldKey,
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Color(0xFF00b3c9),
              bottom: TabBar(
                onTap: (index) {},
                controller: _tabController,
                tabs: listTab,
              ),
              title: Text('Cotação de Veículos'),
            ),
            body: TabBarView(
              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(), //NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
              controller: _tabController,
              children: [
                Form(key: _formkeys[0], child: FormCliente()),
                Form(key: _formkeys[1], child: FormVeiculo()),
                Form(key: _formkeys[2], child: FormContrato()),
                Form(key: _formkeys[3], child: FormFinanceiro(valorFipe)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?